# How to change Textblock button Content When pressed with a Style in a universal App

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have a problem in setting the TextBlock color in my button content,this is my code:

```
<Style  x:Key="ButtonStyle"
    TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#e6e6e6" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#393185" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#00a0e3"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="transparent" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="transparent" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#00a0e3" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                      BorderBrush="#393185"

                      Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                      ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                      VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                      AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

the problem is that the textblock does not change the Foreground color when I press the button
have you please any idea how can I correct my code
thanks for help

Update:

this is my xaml code and the Textblock that I want to change the text color from Gray to #00a0e3 when I press the button:

```
<Button Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource ButtonStyle}}">
                                        <Grid Margin="0" x:Name="Grid2" >
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"  />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Button Grid.Column="0" Click="MenuButton2_Click">
                                            <Image Source="images/3.png" Height="25" Width="25"  x:Name="img2" Margin="0"/>
                                        </Button>
                                        <TextBlock  Text="Restaurant"  Foreground="Gray" x:Name="res3" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Button>
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but in your code you have `<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#00a0e3"/>` and then in pressed state you change foreground to the same color `<DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#00a0e3" />` - is it intentional?

Comment: thanks Sir Romasz for your reply,but this doesn't help me,I have updated my Post Sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Response to the Update,
see you want completely different thing. The TextBlock whose foreground you need to change, is outside the `ContentPresenter` of `Button` control. Hence, through its style you cannot modify the Foreground. You need to add Tap event to the button and from backend code, you can change the foreground color. See the below code.

In XAML --

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" Tapped="MenuButton2_Tapped">
                                        <Image Source="images/3.png" Height="25" Width="25"  x:Name="img2" Margin="0"/>
                                    </Button>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name=restaurantTextBlock  Text="Restaurant"  Foreground="Gray" x:Name="res3" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

In C#---

```
restaurantTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255,0,160,227));//mention any color
```

Comment: I have a question Sir,what is the difference between the click and the Tap Events?

Comment: The Click event was originally defined in Silverlight for desktop Windows and it is only defined for the Button control (and derivatives such as HyperlinkButton). You can think of the Click event as the "traditional" way to handle a Button press. Tap is defined in the UIElement class, which is the parent of many types of controls. You can handle a Tap event in a TextBlock, Image, and many other controls. Button is subclassed from UIElement as well, and thus can also receive Tap events. It is redundant that a Button can receive both Tap and Click events.

Answer (score 1):

As Romasz pointed out, you have set the Foreground color of button same as the foreground color of button when in pressed state i.e #00a0e3 . I think while copying the color hexadecimal code, you may have pasted wrong. Change the color in either Pressed state or initial Foreground test. Your code works though once either of the change is made.

As always, if you find this answer helpful and correct, please vote this answer as correct answer. You are welcome to ask anymore questions if you like.

Comment: thanks Sir for your reply,but this doesn't help :(,I have updated my Post